# How can I combine mutliple JS functions into one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have googled to find out the way to combine my code, I tried many solutions but they never helped me.

I have 3 divs in html and 3 slightly different JS functions against each div. Functions are populating js code.

I want to combine my code like rather than having 3 functions, if there can be only one function that can do the same thing as I want.

What's the best way to do this?

```js
// Random Stars
(function($) {
var generateStars = function(){

  var $galaxy = $(".galaxy1");
  var iterator = 0;

  while (iterator <= 100){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }

};

generateStars();

var generateStars2 = function(){

  var $galaxy = $(".galaxy2");
  var iterator = 0;

  while (iterator <= 25){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }

};

generateStars2();

var generateStars3 = function(){

  var $galaxy = $(".galaxy3");
  var iterator = 0;

  while (iterator <= 50){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }

};

generateStars3();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="galaxy1"></div> 
    <div class="galaxy2"></div> 
    <div class="galaxy3"></div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration is a key pattern in a slightly varied parameters, but similar (or in your case, exact) logic:

## code

```
var generateStars = function($galaxy, threshold){

  var iterator = 0;

  while (iterator <= threshold){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      // using the 'threshold' parameter passed into the function
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * threshold) + 1);
      // no need to re-initialized '$galaxy' as it's now passed into the function
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }

};
```

## usage

```
// getting all the html elements
var $galaxy1 = $(".galaxy1");
var $galaxy2 = $(".galaxy2");
var $galaxy3 = $(".galaxy3");

// passing the properties of the found elements and the threshold 
// to be utilized inside the function
generateStars($galaxy1, 100);
generateStars($galaxy2, 25);
generateStars($galaxy3, 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

#### Changes:

- Made `generateStars1,2,3` to a common function `generateStar` to accept number of stars(`limit`) and element to append(`el`)
- Removed `position` object. Since this object was only used once, moved logic there and removed object.
- Also remove variables `xposition` and `yposition` as only used in calculations and holds `Math.random()`.
- Removed `iterator++` and updated `while(iterator <= limits)` to `while(iterator++ <= limits)`
- Removed `.appendTo(el)` from loop as its a bad practice to manipulate DOM in loop. Instead, created an array and pushed it using `$(el).append(divArray)`

---

#### generateStars function

```js
function generator(el, limit) {
  var iterator = 0;
  var divs = [];
  while (iterator++ <= limit) {
    var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);
    var $div = $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').css({
      "top": ($(el).height() * Math.random()),
      "left": ($(el).width() * Math.random())
    })
    divs.push($div)
  }
  $(el).append(divs)
};
```

---

#### Working Demo

```js
function generator(el, limit) {
  var iterator = 0;
  var divs = [];
  while (iterator++ <= limit) {
    var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);
    var $div = $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').css({
      "top": ($(el).height() * Math.random()),
      "left": ($(el).width() * Math.random())
    })
    divs.push($div)
  }
  $(el).append(divs)
};

(function($) {
  var generateStars = function() {
    var limits = [100, 25, 50];
    $('div[class^="galaxy"]').each(function(i, el) {
      generator(el, limits[i])
    })
  }
  generateStars();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.star {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

[class^='galaxy'] {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="galaxy1"></div>
  <div class="galaxy2"></div>
  <div class="galaxy3"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```js
var star_type_multipler = {
   0: 100,
   1: 25,
   2: 50
}

var $i = 0;
$('.galaxy').each(function() {

  var $galaxy = $(this);
  var iterator = 0;
  var multipler = star_type_multipler[$i++]

  while (iterator <= multipler){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * multipler) + 1);
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '">x</div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }
});
```

```css
.star { position: fixed; }
body { width: 500px; height: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="galaxy1 galaxy">&nbsp;</div> 
    <div class="galaxy2 galaxy">&nbsp;</div> 
    <div class="galaxy3 galaxy">&nbsp;</div> 
</body>
```

Just don't forget to add `galaxy` class to each `div` like above

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = [100, 25, 50];

$("div[class^='galaxy']").each(function(index){
    generateStars($(this), options[index]);
});

function generateStars($galaxy, limit){
  for(var iterator = 0; iterator < limit, iterator++){
     var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * limit) + 1);
     $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
        "top" : $galaxy.height() * Math.random(),
        "left" : $galaxy.width() * Math.random()
     });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the arguments that are variable, i.e. can change from case to case.
Here, you can pass the element id and a coefficient.

Also, in this case seems that it's better to use ids, because they are unique `$('#some-id')`. On the contrary, same class can be assigned to multiple elements, so jquery will get them all `$('.some-class')`;

```
var generateStars = function(elementId, coef){

  var $galaxy = $(elementId);
  var iterator = 0;

  while (iterator <= coef){
      var xposition = Math.random();
      var yposition = Math.random();
      var star_type = Math.floor((Math.random() * coef) + 1);
      var position = {
          "x" : $galaxy.width() * xposition,
          "y" : $galaxy.height() * yposition,
      };

      $('<div class="star star-type-' + star_type + '"></div>').appendTo($galaxy).css({
          "top" : position.y,
          "left" : position.x
      });

      iterator++;
  }

};

generateStars('#galaxy1', 100);
generateStars('#galaxy2', 50);
generateStars('#galaxy3', 25);
```